# Position: Sticky example in JS Fiddle

Tags: webkit, position, sticky

I am testing the new position:sticky feature but it does not appear to work.

CSS

```
   .slide {
        width:300px;
        height:400px;
        border:1px solid #888;
        border-radius:8px;
        position:relative;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    .slide > ul {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        position:relative;
    }
    .slide > ul > li {
        min-height:20px;
        display:block;
        padding:10px;
        background:#F8F8F8;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #CCC;
        list-style:none;
    }
    .slide > ul > li.title {
        min-height:12px;
        background:#888;
        colour:#FFF;
        font-weight:bold;
        position:-webkit-sticky;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="slide">
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Settings</li>
        <li>General</li>
        <li>Social</li>
        <li>Search Engine</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Privacy</li>
        <li>Personal</li>
        <li>Business</li>
        <li>Enigma</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Settings</li>
        <li>General</li>
        <li>Social</li>
        <li>Search Engine</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Privacy</li>
        <li>Personal</li>
        <li>Business</li>
        <li>Enigma</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/78kxU/3/

Answer (score 1):

`position: sticky` requires you to specify either a `top` or `bottom` CSS property in order to determine where/when the sticky element should begin sticking. You should also specify the un-vendor-prefixed value for forwards-compatibility (in this case, it seems to be required, at least on Chrome 30.0.1599.101).

So, in other words, add these two lines to your `.slide > ul > li.title` style rules:

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46gpu/